# Compound View and Restore State

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have a compound view that has an icon and a `EditText`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edit_text_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edit_text_padding"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edit_text_padding"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edit_text_padding"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/edit_text_padding_left"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/edit_text_padding_left"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        style="@style/edit_text" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm using this compound view in the login form and other places in my application. Sometimes I need to save the contents of the fields whenever the `onSaveInstanceState()` occurs. When I'm restoring the state, all the fields will have the same value of the last `EditText` fields, because, in general, all `EditText` views have the same id (`etContent`).

Besides that, if you have a login activity (email and password fields), this will generate a security issue as the first field (email) will have the value of the last field (in this case the password).

Any suggestion to fix this issue?

Comment: How are you restoring its state?

Comment: Right now, im not using any code to restore the state. I went to the developer options and toggle the "don't keep activities" switch to on. If you have an username such as "user1234" and a password "1234", all fields will have the value of "1234". I just want to keep the username. Additionally, there is any way to disable the restore state for a specific edit text field?

Comment: I got it - but is this scenario (1234 appearing on every editText) happening right now or you just fear that it might happen? Moreover, how are you using the layout you posted? Are you using `<include>`?

Comment: I'm using an compound view. In the activity xml i have <packagename.CustomCompoundView />. This situation is happening right now...I am trying to figure out a possible solution to this issue.

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Couldn't you differentiate the ID's on the <CustomCompoundView/> with `android:id` ?

Comment: This is not a pretty solution but a work around. You could always after the super call in onRestoreState, clear the EditText.

Comment: I can not differentiate the views. I could generate an id for each field, but i think this is not a pretty solution. The GuilhE solution is also a good solution. However, i prefer to manage the values and the restore state with the CompoundView class. I manage to apply the clear solution. Thanks for all suggestions.